# Piczard Image Cropping is not working

Tags: .net, image, resize-image

I am having an issue with the Piczard image croping tool.[Piczard Cropping Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7cfK.png)

The Problem is once I click on Browse button cropping tool appears but without any option or controls of cropping. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Which Windows and operating system are you running?

Comment: It is not working on any operating system. I have tested it on Windows 10 and windows server 2012

Comment: Try it may work http://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeCarvings.Piczard/

Comment: Nopes still same issue

Comment: here you can find everything about [piczard](https://piczard.com/docs/help/v1/online/).